# sort numpy array of lists

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

We are given a numpy array (`ndarray`) of lists (`dtype=object`), and would like to  return a similar array of lists where each list is sorted. Is there an efficient way of doing this (i.e. without for loop etc)?

Please don't offer `np.vectorize()` as a solution as this is implemented as a for loop and is thus inefficient.

For example:

```
a=np.array([[5,4],[6,7,2],[8,1,9]],dtype=object)
```

so a is:

```
array([list([5, 4]), list([6, 7, 2]), list([8, 1, 9])], dtype=object)
```

and we would like the function to sort it so we would get:

```
array([list([4, 5]), list([2, 6, 7]), list([1, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: So using a list comprehension for example is too slow?

Comment: Numpy's speed comes from homogeneous rectangular arrays, not magic. Numpy won't be faster for your problem, unless np.sort is faster than timsort for your individual lists.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I disagree, the speed comes also comes from vectorizing by pushing loops into the c, and that does not necessarily require rectangular arrays.

Comment: Python's sort is also written in C. A lot of numpy speedup comes from caching in the CPU which is gone if your array only contains pointers to data far apart.

Comment: @RaySteam list comprehension is possible, but requires conversion back to numpy. It might turn out to be the fastest, but I was wondering if there is an alternative within numpy to do this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak just to be clear, I am not trying to avoid python sorting, but the loop which iterates over the elements of the array.

Comment: Side note: can you time how long it takes to 1. just loop over your array with a no-op and 2. loop and sort with `sorted` or `np.sort`? I would expect 1. to be negligible compared to 2.

Comment: `numpy` loses most of it's speed advantage with `dtype=object`. You probably aren't going to get more of a speed-up than `np.vectorize`.

Comment: `frompyfunc` often is twice as fast as iteration when working with the elements of a object array.

Comment: The fastest `numpy` code doesn't just iterate in C, it operates directly on the `ndarray` data-buffer in C.  But the elements of an object dtype array are references to Python objects (lists), just like the elements of a Python list.  Object dtype arrays may be convenient, but they are, generally speaking, slower than Python lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example, and an expanded version for time tests:

```
In [202]: a=np.array([[5,4],[6,7,2],[8,1,9]],dtype=object)                      
In [203]: A = a.repeat(100)
```

Applying Python list sort to each element:

```
In [204]: np.array([sorted(i) for i in a])                                      
Out[204]: array([list([4, 5]), list([2, 6, 7]), list([1, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Using [**`frompyfunc`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) to do the same:

```
In [205]: np.frompyfunc(sorted,1,1)(a)                                          
Out[205]: array([list([4, 5]), list([2, 6, 7]), list([1, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Some timings:

```
In [206]: timeit np.array(list(map(sorted, A)))                                 
168 µs ± 221 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [207]: timeit np.array([sorted(i) for i in A])                               
181 µs ± 249 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`map` is a little faster than a list comprehension.  I prefer the readability of the comprehension.

A pure list version is quite a bit faster:

```
In [208]: %%timeit temp=A.tolist() 
     ...: list(map(sorted, temp)) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                       
88.3 µs ± 70.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`frompyfunc` is faster than the array map, and almost as good as the pure list version:

```
In [209]: timeit np.frompyfunc(sorted,1,1)(A)                                   
97.3 µs ± 1.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

That's the pattern I've seen before.  `frompyfunc` is the fastest way to apply functions to elements of an object dtype array, but it seldom is better than a list based iteration.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. So how much of the difference between `np.array(list(map(sorted, A)))` and the pure python version comes from the need to convert the list back to a numpy ndarray at the end?

Comment: Most of the difference lies in that conversion back to array.  Starting with a list helps some, but not nearly as much.

Comment: Great, thanks. Unforunately I need this to end up as a numpy array (for other fast operations), so I guess there is no getting around this.

Comment: @Bitwise heads-up: those "other fast operations" might also be faster in native python.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks, in a general case that might be true, but unfortunately that is not the case for me.

Comment: On my Mac both `frompyfunc` and the "pure version" take ~88µs. (numpy==1.16.0)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array(list(map(sorted, a)))
```

gives:

```
array([list([4, 5]), list([2, 6, 7]), list([1, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Good solution, but not numpy.